# EF Core 5, How to define multiple "one-many" relationships?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-5.0

I'm creating a freelance task management app. Here is the logic. These are the 3 POCOs involved

### User (LoggedIn User)

> 1. A user can create any number of clients
> 2. A user can create any number of projects
> 3. A user is created, updated by another user

### Client (Freelance Client)

> 1. A client can have any number of projects
> 2. A client is created, updated by a user

### Project

> 1. A project should have only one client
> 2. A project is created, updated by a user

These are my Entities. I'm using Code-First approach and uses SQLServer. I removed many properties for posting here

## User Entity

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }        
}
```

## Client Entity

```
public class Client
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }        

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

## Project Entity

```
public class Project
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ProjectLogo { get; set; }        

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }       
}
```

I'm now facing so many issues with ForginKeys and mappings. What is wrong with the entity mappings here?
I can't insert 2 rows in clients table with same CreatedById, EF is constraining it with unique values.

This is my fluent mappings

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //User
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(a => a.UpdatedBy).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        //Project
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne(a => a.UpdatedBy).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        //Client
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasOne(a => a.UpdatedBy).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
```

How can I implement this requirement?

Comment: Those should all be one-many relationships, not one-one.

Comment: Hi David, Are you mentioning about User-Project or User-Client as many-many relationship? Is this issues happen because I'm adding "User CreatedBy" & "User UpdatedBy" properties on all these 3 classes? In that case what can be an alternative?

Comment: Those are all 1-many relationships.  To simplify things to start, try removing all the CreatedBy and UpdatedBy relationships.  Then once you get that working you can consider adding them back, or using Shadow Properties for those. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties

Comment: As you suggested, I edited question for 1:N relationships. I removed CreatedBy, UpdatedBy from entities and everything works fine. But when I add those, I can't insert 2 entries on Client table since EFCore makes int columns "CreatedById" & "UpdatedById" unique and assigns a FK with User table. I can't insert 2 clients created by same UserId, Error says failed due to duplicate CreatedById identified while inserting

Comment: A foreign key in a 1-1 relationship is always unique.  Should be `modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithMany()`

Comment: Hi David. Thank you man. It solves my issue. Can you post this as an answer, I'll mark accepted and close. Might be helpful to someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a relationship issue with my entities. I made my properties look like

```
public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }
```

And added fluent mapping

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            //User
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(a => a.UpdatedBy).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
            //Project
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne(a => a.UpdatedBy).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
            //Client
            modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasOne(a => a.UpdatedBy).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
```

Adding One-Many relationship resolved my issue. Thanks to @David